# Lookup table variable in Google Tag manager for Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, lookup-tables

I am using Google Analytics with Google Tag Manager in an Android app. I want to send release and debug build analytics data to separate Google Analytics accounts. I want to avoid including the Analytics account ids as string literals in the app code. I also want to avoid the option of having one set of tags for each build type (firing on different triggers).

It seems that in Google Tag Manager for web you can use the Lookup table variable type to accomplish this, but according to the official Google Tag Manager documentation this variable type is not available for mobile apps.

Is it correct that the Lookup table variable type is not available for mobile apps? Is it possible to accomplish this some other way?

Comment: Hello @Daniel Peterson have you found a way?

Comment: Hi @AndreaBaccega There does not seem to be a way unfortunately!

Comment: Same problem here. One possible workaround is using the rest api https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v1/reference/accounts/containers/variables/list#request through the java wrapper https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/tagmanager/v1 . Anyway, this is so annoying..

Comment: Even i am looking for a solution, what i am doing right now is log the event multiple times on Firebase with diff keys for lookup table variable. This is not the right implementation i know.